# Discord.py ctx commands not responding

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

None of my ctx commands work. Here I'll give an example. When I say `p!test` I want it to print `hi` and say `test`, but it's not responding. Can someone help?

```py
@client.command()
async def test(ctx):
    print('hi')
    await ctx.channel.send('test')
```

Comment: Do you have an `on_message` event?

Comment: `@client.event
async def on_message(message):`?

Comment: Yes, did you process commands in the `on_message` event?

Comment: What does that mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using a `on_message` event, you have to 'process commands' in the last line of the event. Otherwise, your commands won't work.

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    ...
    await client.process_commands(message)
```

## Reference

- [`discord.ext.commands.Bot.process_commands`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.process_commands)

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Nothing would work, like it wouldn't respond, as if it weren't even in the code

Comment: If you process commands in the `on_message` event, it should work.

Comment: OMG THANK YOU SO MUCH